mounting o-ran-uplane-conf yang module to o-ran-agg-uplane-conf yang module using sysrepo
I would like to push configuration data into the 5G distributed unit, whatever is obtained from the Radio unit using the o-ran yang modules. among which there is an aggregated yang module o-ran-agg-uplane-conf in which a mount point is defined to mount o-ran-uplane-conf yang module.
Filling the following configuration data using yang schema mounts
 "<schema-mounts xmlns=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-yang-schema-mount\">"
 "  <namespace>"
 "    <prefix>o-ran-uplane-conf</prefix>"
 "    <uri>urn:o-ran:uplane-conf</uri>"
 "  </namespace>"
 "  <mount-point>"
 "    <module>aggregated-o-ru</module>"
 "    <label>uplane-conf-root</label>"
 "    <config>false</config>"
 "    <inline/>"
 "  </mount-point>"
 "</schema-mounts>"

Can someone please verify if this is correct because populating this using sysrepo APIs, I am still not able to populate the RU configuration data in the following manner.
<aggregated-o-ru xmlns="urn:o-ran:agg-base:1.0">
  <aggregation>
    <ru-instance>1</ru-instance>
    <uplane-conf-model xmlns="urn:o-ran:agg-uplane-conf:1.0">
        <user-plane-configuration xmlns="urn:o-ran:uplane-conf:1.0">
          <tx-array-carriers>
            <name>txarraycarrier0</name>
            <absolute-frequency-center>646668</absolute-frequency-center>
            <center-of-channel-bandwidth>3700020000</center-of-channel-bandwidth>
            <channel-bandwidth>100000000</channel-bandwidth>
            <active>INACTIVE</active>
            <rw-duplex-scheme>TDD</rw-duplex-scheme>
            <rw-type>NR</rw-type>
            <gain>27.0</gain>
            <downlink-radio-frame-offset>0</downlink-radio-frame-offset>
            <downlink-sfn-offset>0</downlink-sfn-offset>
          </tx-array-carriers>
          <rx-array-carriers>
            <name>rxarraycarrier0</name>
            <absolute-frequency-center>646668</absolute-frequency-center>
            <center-of-channel-bandwidth>3700020000</center-of-channel-bandwidth>
            <channel-bandwidth>100000000</channel-bandwidth>
            <active>INACTIVE</active>
            <downlink-radio-frame-offset>0</downlink-radio-frame-offset>
            <downlink-sfn-offset>0</downlink-sfn-offset>
            <gain-correction>0.0</gain-correction>
            <n-ta-offset>25600</n-ta-offset>
          </rx-array-carriers>
        </user-plane-configuration>
    </uplane-conf-model>
  </aggregation>
</aggregated-o-ru>

can someone let me know if at all I am doing this correctly.
I would like to know how to mount yang modules into the mount points appropriately using sysrepo.

The yang-schema mount data should look like the following, this is mentioned in the o-ran o1 specifications.
  <schema-mounts>
        <namespace> 
            <prefix> o-ran-uplane-conf</prefix>
            <uri> urn:o-ran:uplane-conf:1.0</uri>
        </namespace>
        <mount-point>
            <module> o-ran-agg-uplane-conf</module>
            <label>uplane-conf-root</label>
            <config>true</config>
            <inline></inline>
        </mount-point>
    </schema-mounts>

I was able to push the aggregated configuration as follows
<aggregated-o-ru xmlns="urn:o-ran:agg-base:1.0">
  <aggregation>
    <ru-instance>1</ru-instance>
    <uplane-conf-model xmlns="urn:o-ran:agg-uplane-conf:1.0">
                    <user-plane-configuration xmlns="urn:o-ran:uplane-conf:1.0">
                          <tx-array-carriers>
                            <name>txarraycarrier0</name>
                            <absolute-frequency-center>641280</absolute-frequency-center>
                            <center-of-channel-bandwidth>3700020000</center-of-channel-bandwidth>
                            <channel-bandwidth>100000000</channel-bandwidth>
                            <active>INACTIVE</active>
                            <rw-duplex-scheme>TDD</rw-duplex-scheme>
                            <rw-type>NR</rw-type>
                            <gain>27.0</gain>
                            <downlink-radio-frame-offset>0</downlink-radio-frame-offset>
                            <downlink-sfn-offset>0</downlink-sfn-offset>
                          </tx-array-carriers>
                          <rx-array-carriers>
                            <name>rxarraycarrier0</name>
                            <absolute-frequency-center>641280</absolute-frequency-center>
                            <center-of-channel-bandwidth>100000000</center-of-channel-bandwidth>
                            <channel-bandwidth>100000000</channel-bandwidth>
                            <active>INACTIVE</active>
                            <downlink-radio-frame-offset>0</downlink-radio-frame-offset>
                            <downlink-sfn-offset>0</downlink-sfn-offset>
                            <gain-correction>0.0</gain-correction>
                            <n-ta-offset>25600</n-ta-offset>
                          </rx-array-carriers>
                        </user-plane-configuration>
    </uplane-conf-model>
  </aggregation>
</aggregated-o-ru>

